# Generalization of index 2 subgroups are normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup of index $p$, where $p$ is a prime. If $\operatorname{gcd}(|H|, p-1)=1$, then $H$ must be normal. Does somebody have a quick proof of this?

Comment: I've never seen this.  The generalization I have seen is:

If H is a subgroup of index p, where p is the smallest prime dividing |G|, then H is normal.

http://planetmath.org/?op=getobj&from=objects&name=NormalityOfSubgroupsOfPrimeIndex

Comment: @Numth: Then this would be a corollary of that, since if $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, no smaller prime can divide $|H|$, and thus $\gcd(|h|,p-1)=1$.

Comment: @joriki I know.  I just provided a partial answer.

Comment: here's one generalization (not the one you want): if $[G:H]=p$ and $p$ is the minimal prime divisor of $G$ then $H$ is normal ( http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_index_equal_to_least_prime_divisor_of_group_order_is_normal )

Comment: @yoyo That's what I already said.

Comment: Yes guys, if p is the smallest prime dividing the order of G, then it is well known and not to involved. But this is something different and a very nice theorem indeed.

Comment: very good theorem, where did you see it ?

Comment: @Mesel, this a Theorem of Bioch and Van der Waall from the seventies, see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073736/normal-subgroups-in-groups-of-odd-order/1606105#1606105

Comment: @NickyHekster: I wonder whether character teoritic proof can be done ? For starting, Let $\chi=(1_H)^G$ then $\chi$ is a character of $G$ with degree $\chi(1)=p=$ and $ker(\chi)=Core(H)$. The above result is equivalent to say that every irreducable constitute of $\chi$ is linear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By induction on $|G|$, we can assume that there is no non-trivial normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ contained in $H$.  Thus the action of $G$ on the conjugates of $H$ gives an embedding of $G$ into $S_p$, of order $p!$.  Thus $|H|$ divides $(p-1)!$, and so $p$ does not divide $|H|$.  Thus the Sylow p-groups of $G$ are cyclic of order $p$.

Now if any $h\in H$ normalized a Sylow p-group $P$, then $h$ would map into $Aut(P)\cong C_{p-1}$, and by hypothesis the image would be trivial.  That is, any $h\in H$ normalizing $P$ also centralizes $P$.  It follows that $N_G(P)=C_G(P)$, and by the Burnside Transfer theorem, $G$ has a normal subgroup $M$ of index $p$.  Of course, any Sylow q-group of $H$ is then contained in $M$, and so $H$ is contained in $M$; that is, $H=M$ is normal.

Comment: Should probably mention there is a slightly faster way to do this, using Frobenius's theorem on normal p-complements; basically, since we can assume $|G|=pm$ where $(m,p-1)=1$, we get a normal p-complement $M$ in $G$ (see for example Corollary 9.22 in Isaacs's Algebra), and then we show $H=M$ just as I did in the end.

Comment: Another short proof: Suppose note, and let $H_1,\ldots,H_p$ be the conjugates of $H$; then $G$ acts on these as a transitive group of degree $p$, and since by hypothesis $G$ doesn't live in $AGL(1,p)$, $G$ must be 2-transitive; that is, $(p-1)$ divides the order of $G_1=H_1$, contradiction.  This proof shows something stronger: if $H$ is not normal, then either $|H|$ divides $(p-1)$ or vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, in my "stronger" statement above, I was thinking of the core-free case.

Comment: It might help to put the extra line $N_G(P) = PN_H(P)$ in your proof.

Answer (score 6):

Note: As pointed out in the comments this answer is missing a crucial detail, and unfortunately I have no idea if it can be salvaged.

This is a slightly more elementary way to show this:

Assume $H$ is not normal. Then clearly $N_G(H) = H$ and $G$ acts on the $|G:H| = p$ conjugates of $H$ by conjugation. The stabilizer of $H$ under this action is just $H$, which then acts on the other $p-1$ conjugates.

The orbit of a $gHg^{-1}$ under this action consists of all $g'Hg'^{-1}$ with $g'\in Hg$ and thus all the orbits have the same size. On the other hand, their sizes all divide the order of $H$, which is a contradiction since $gcd(|H|,p-1) = 1$

Comment: Why do all orbits have the same size? That is, why does $ | H^g\cap H | = | H^{g^2}\cap H | $?

Comment: Tobias, I agree with Steve D. your proof is false. Aren't you mixing up the action of G on the conjugates of H and the action of H on these conjugates?